# How can i deploy my worklight project to my blackberry device..?

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, ibm-mobilefirst

I have packaged my application successfully using ripple with chrome.
What process i have to follow to deploy my app to my blackberry device for testing purpose?

Comment: Is it a BB10 bar file or a BB7 cod file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways.

1. You can try using the [BlackBerry Desktop Manager](http://us.blackberry.com/software/desktop.html) software which should allow you application syncing.
2. You can use the [JavaLoader commandline tool](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/loading_your_app_on_a_smartphone_1876977_11.html), provided by BlackBerry.

Personally, I use JavaLoader.
It is a simple one-liner in CMD: `javaloader load path-to-cod-file`

The one-liner above assumes you have added JavaLoader (an .exe in the bin folder of the BlackBerry WebWorks SDK for BlackBerry OS 6/7) to your PATH, so that it will be available for useage like in the example)

---

Please keep an mind that after you generate the .cod file using Ripple, what you basically have is an actual BlackBerry (WebWorks) project, the way to deploy it would be the same as any other BlackBerry application, whether it was created by Worklight or any other software.

Comment: Thanx for your help Idan. But will you please elaborate the procedure for installing my app through BlackBerry's Destop Software..??

Comment: See my edited answer - I've made the text to a link. It's software that you download from BlackBerry's website. Install it, sync. Should work. If not, use option 2.

Comment: For using javaloader i connected my blackberry via usb to windows....in which mode i have to connect the device to window...???

Comment: hello idan, i have used javaloader to deploy my app to my device it give a success message. But when i tried to run my app it gives an error message like "Module Mybbapp attempts to access a secure API"...and application stops after that....Plz help me regarding this...Is there any setting that i have to modify ...???

Comment: It means you didn't SIGN the app. You need to Package & Sign it.

Comment: Follow this BlackBerry-provided article about how to get signing keys and setup your computer with them: https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/signing_setup_smartphone_apps_1920010_11.html

Comment: Is it necessary to sign every application even if i have to use that just for the test purpose...???

Comment: I don't think so, probably not - but then again this is not a Worklight question, but a BlackBerry one. This question is answered.